# Is it possible to add a condition class to the master page?

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, css, master-page, delegate-control

I want to add the class `ms-hide`to the body of my master page depending on certain conditions.

I'm trying to do something like delegate controls where, based on a feature I add or remove this class from my body.

I'm doing a lot of DOM manipulation on my project sites and I want to hide the body until it's ready then fade it in.

Answer (score 0):

One option, showing the power of CSS

add a STYLE tag to your document, preferably in the HEAD, but can be placed anywhere

```
<style id="hiddenHTML">
  :root body{
     visibility:hidden;
   }
</style>
```

This hides the body tag, but you can still do DOM manipulations

Once you are ready you disable the whole STYLE definition

```
document.getElementById('hiddenHTML').disabled=true;
```

Comment: Well I can already use `ms-hide` for styling so that's fine. My issue is that I need the styling to be determined based on some variable server site or on render. Essentially, I have `/projects/home` (I don't need to hide things there) but then I have `/projects/proj-2016/1( to n)` So I'm trying to find a way to have this class applied to the body depending on what collection I'm in or if a feature has been enabled (like delegate controls) etc.

Comment: Apply a UserCustomAction ScriptLink so it executes on every page and whack that class in with JS

Comment: I'll try that. Hopefully it's fast enough to apply the styling right away. I was assigning styling on $.ready but then it would stutter between displayed and hidden, then displayed again when my DOM manipulations where done.

Comment: That's why you do the reverse with the STYLE, hide always and show on /projects/home